# DBAs not allowing to set SERIALIZED_CONTEXT as clob for Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

We are planning to use Spring Batch is our project. As per metadata schema, we need to get some tables created, `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT` and `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT`.

In these table we need to create `SERIALIZED_CONTEXT` column with clob datatype. Our DBAs are not ready to create tables with clob data type (can create memory issues). Can someone help to get alternative solution?

We have not tried but can we change it to some other datatype.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? That said, you should escalate this and get a manager to overrule your DBAs; it sounds like DBAs in your organization have a bit too much power, and using spurious reasons to reject things.